# ZeroMQ Clone pattern and late-joining client

Tags: zeromq

The ZeroMQ guide describes in the [Getting an Out-of-Band Snapshot](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Getting-an-Out-of-Band-Snapshot) section that

> The client first subscribes to updates and then makes a state request. This guarantees that the state is going to be newer than the oldest update it has.

How does making the subscription first guarantee that the client will receive all updates newer than the snapshot state? For example

1. Client subscribes to state updates
2. Client requests the state snapshot
3. Client receives the state snapshot
4. State changes happen at the server
5. Client's subscription to state changes is complete

So the client would miss the state changes happening on step 4. Is this scenario possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow me to describe the process a little more fully:

1. Server publishes updates as they occur
2. New client ***subscribes*** to updates (client `SUB` to server `PUB`)
3. New client ***requests*** current state from server (client `DEALER` to server `ROUTER`) - (***IMPORTANT***: it's assumed it will take longer for this request to reach the server and begin building the snapshot this than it takes for the `SUB` socket to finish connecting and subscribe to updates - this is generally a reasonable assumption, but note it)
4. Server builds snapshot of current state to respond to request
5. Server continues to publish updates as they occur
6. New client queues all of these updates that they are subscribed to - does not process them yet (this is part of ZMQ "for free")
7. Server sends back current state (***IMPORTANT***: *If* the state request from the client occurred after the subscription completed, then one of two scenarios is true: **either (A)** there were no new updates after the new client joined, and so the state is just the history before the new client joined, **or (B)** there were new updates that are both in the state *and* queued in the client's `SUB` socket. **(A)** is trivially correct, so we'll focus on **(B)**.)
8. New client processes the state - this brings it up to current.
9. New client begins to process the messages in the `SUB` socket.  If there are any we check them against the history we now have.  If we already have this update (from the state), we discard it.  If we don't, it's a new message and we deal with it.
10. New client continues to process the messages as normal, all caught up to date and processing all new messages.

... even though in the example code, the `SUB` socket doesn't start to `recv()` messages until after it receives the state, it's still getting them from the publisher and queuing them until it's ready to process them, so there's no scenario where an update is missed, instead the opposite scenario where messages are duplicated is planned for and handled.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The assumption in the step 3 of your description was precisely the point of my question. So if I understand correctly, to guarantee consistent states with the Clone pattern, we have to make this one timing related assumption.

Comment: The reason it's a reasonable assumption is because both connections are happening under the same circumstances - there's no reason why the `SUB` socket should take longer to finish its connection than the `DEALER` socket. I'd of course benchmark that if I intended to rely on it.